# Level of water in a tank after two minutes of emptying

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An inverted right circular cone of height 1 meter and base radius of 0.5 meter that is filled with water that is draining out of the bottom out of a hole (circular orifice) of diameter 2cm.  What is the level of the water in the tank after two minutes?

I know to use the following formula:

$$\dfrac{dh}{dt}=-\dfrac{A_o}{A_c}\sqrt{2hg}$$

I know now that $A_c=A_c(h)$ now depends on $h$ ($A_c$ is the horizontal cross-section of each slice of the cone). I am also told to ignore the geometrical change that the orifice would make to the cone.

I am teaching myself differential equations but I am having a wicked time with following through on these types of problems.  I am pretty good at working with just the formulas of first-order ODEs and using integrating factors but I am lost at this point.  Thank you for any input!

Comment: If you don't know/say in **what way** $\;A_c\;$ depends on the differentiated function $\;h\;$ , I can't see how to solve this diff. eq.

Comment: The ratio of the area of the circle to its height.  As the height decreases, the area of the circle will also decrease because of proportionality.